# How to parse multipart form-data using only EL

Tags: jsp, el, multipartform-data

Similar to `${param.key}`, is there a way to interpret a multipart/form-data encrypted form using EL without Java?

If not possible, is there a workaround to include a file input in a form without using multipart/form-data  encryption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`multipart/form-data` is used to upload file. This could be big and uploading it could take a while. In order not to block other incoming requests the processing could be asynchronous.

**With Java:**

**@MultipartConfig**:

For a servlet receiving multipart/form-data you have to add the `@MultipartConfig` annotation in front of the servlet, in order to get the values of the plain text parameters by calling `request.getParameter("notFileFieldName");`. Otherwise the call will return null.

But with the file and its content, it didn't work this way.
The file name, content-type, size and content could be retrieved from the `Part` object returned by
`request.getPart("theFileFieldName");`

For JSP you can add the following snipplet in the web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>UploadFile</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/path/form.jsp</jsp-file>
    <multipart-config></multipart-config>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UploadFile</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/path/form.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Where the line `<multipart-config></multipart-config>` activate the above behavior for the JSP.
So `${param.notFileFieldName}` will be evaluated to its value.
But not the `${param.theFileFieldName}`

**AsyncContext**  could used to process the upload

- [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/AsyncContext.html)
- [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets012.htm)

But you won't a java solution.

**With Javascript: FileReader()**

A basic example how you can read file on the client side. (without upload) 
Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL

HTML

```
<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
<img src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
```

JavaScript:

```
function previewFile() {
  var preview = document.querySelector('img');
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }, false);

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

[try it on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/api/mdn/)

If upload is needed it could be done AJAX.

Answer (score -1):

If you use the annotation @MultipartConfig you may need to add a file size, eg:

```
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize=16177215)
```